# How outdoor/wild plants survive without any proper human support?

Tags: botany

I will take care of indoor plants because it was growing in my lawn
if I don't care then **parasitic vines** will destroy my plants.

But how plants take care of itself which are still surviving in forest without any human support?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What research have you done before asking it here?